# Cannot publish alpha version to npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to publish an alpha version of my package to `npm`.
I'm executing this commands:

 `npm version 1.0.0-alpha.1
 npm publish --tag 1.0.0-alpha.1`

but instead of publishing, I'm getting an error:

`npm ERR! Tag name must not be a valid SemVer range: 1.0.0-alpha.1`

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8531

Comment: But I have the latest tag `latest: 1.0.0-alpha.0`, so why i cannot use the tag `1.0.0-alpha.1`?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem as you. According to the documentation (http://doc.codingdict.com/npm-ref/all.html):

> ## Caveats
>
> Because dist-tags share the same namespace as semver, avoid
> using tag names that may cause a conflict. The best practice is to
> avoid using tags beginning with a number or the letter "v".

So you don't have to specify the tag when you publish. You can just do this:-

```
npm version prerelease --preid=alpha.1
npm publish
```

If you want to specify the tag, you should do this:-

```
npm version prerelease --preid=alpha.1
npm publish --tag=alpha.1
```

Hope this helps!